# Should I use a constraint?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm developing a Twitter-like system, and have a model to record who follows who. There are two fields and both fields are foreign keys and point to the User model.

Clearly you wouldn't want a follower-followee record duplicated, so I'm using the `unique_together` attribute in the inner `Meta` class, in order that the follower-followee pair is unique. Trying to violate this throws `IntegrityError` and 500 status code.

This feels like a "second line of defence" as my view and template code doesn't give a user the chance to follow someone twice.

Should I/can I do something similar to ensure you can't follow yourself?

The view and template that lists all users (each with a button to click to follow that user) does not list the currently logged in user, so there should be no opportunity to follow yourself. But I don't have anything equivalent to `unique_together`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude, no.

I don't know *why* you're doing this, but assuming it isn't for a uni project with a lunatic professor, you're wasting your time.

That is, if he's not a lunatic he's not going to try and hack the following/followee . And so what if he does?
If its for a startup-idea, then spend less time solving this (trivial) problem and more time working on whatever business model or marketing or whathaveyou thing you *need* to do.

A little bug isn't going to be a show stopper.

If you're being contracted out, leave it as a bug and get the conteact extended to fix it :)

If you just want to fix this, just do a check in the model or the validation that the follower isn't the same as the followee

Comment: I'm probably a bit OCD about it, but I hope you see why I asked -from a newbie's point of view it seems weird that you have `unique_together` and you obviously write code to stop this being violated, but you don't have an equivalent to this in another situation which seems similar-ish (or is it?). And it's hard to know what belongs where (model or view in this case), and what's worth bothering with. When you say "check in the model" do you mean add a method to my model?

Comment: attempted +1 "get the contract extended" -I'll remember that advice for future :)  (not actually allowed to upvote yet)